# Error when attempting to read an .xlsm file

Tags: c#, excel-2007, office-interop

Now I have excel file of extension .xlsm, and I need to read and write using C#.
I tried to use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel,

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application ObjExcel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
Workbook ObjWorkBook;
Worksheet ObjWorkSheet;

ObjWorkBook = ObjExcel.Workbooks.Open(excelFilename,Type.Missing,Type.Missing,Type.Missing,Type.Missing,Type.Missing,Type.Missing,Type.Missing,Type.Missing,Type.Missing,Type.Missing,Type.Missing,Type.Missing,Type.Missing,Type.Missing);
ObjWorkSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet) ObjWorkBook.Sheets[1];

if (ObjWorkSheet != null)
{
    Range usedRange = ObjWorkSheet.UsedRange;
    if (usedRange != null)
    {
        for (int rowIndex = 1; rowIndex < usedRange.Rows.Count; rowIndex++)
        {
            for (int colIndex = 1; colIndex < usedRange.Columns.Count; colIndex++)
            {
                string firstName = ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)ObjWorkSheet.Cells[rowIndex, colIndex]).Value2.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

however, I found error Object reference not set to an instance of an object when reading cells..although I replaced another new excel file.xlsm and it read with no errors... 
Also, The file I'm trying to read has macros...

Any Solutions ?!

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Are you using a proper version of Office (2007+) interop assemblies to open the Macro-enabled workbook?

Comment: I would check that workbook. I copied your code, added some Console.Writelines and it works for me. I created a workbook that had macros as well.